# getsnapshot speedup

Tags: matlab, image-processing

the [`getsnapshot`](http://www.mathworks.it/help/toolbox/imaq/getsnapshot.html) function takes a lot of time executing since (I guess) initializes the webcam every time is called. This is a problem if you want to acquire images with a high framerate.

I trick I casually discovered is to call the [`preview`](http://www.mathworks.it/help/toolbox/imaq/preview.html) function, which keeps the webcam handler open making `getsnapshot` almost instantaneous, but it keeps a small preview window open:

```
% dummy example
cam = videoinput(...);
preview(cam);

while(1)
    img = getsnapshot(cam);
    % do stuff
end
```

Is there a "cleaner" way to speedup `getsnapshot`? (without preview window opened)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could use the new "machine vision" toolbox which is specially built for vision applications. See code below:

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'RGB24_320x240'); %select input device

hvpc = vision.VideoPlayer;   %create video player object

src = getselectedsource(vid);
vid.FramesPerTrigger =1;
vid.TriggerRepeat = Inf;
vid.ReturnedColorspace = 'rgb';
src.FrameRate = '30';
start(vid)

%start main loop for image acquisition
for t=1:500
  imgO=getdata(vid,1,'uint8');    %get image from camera
  hvpc.step(imgO);    %see current image in player
end
```

As you can see, you can acquire the image with getdata. The bottleneck in video applications in Matlab was the preview window, which delayed to code substantially. The new vision.VideoPlayer is **a lot** faster (i have used this code in real time vision applications in Matlab. When i had written the first version without the vision toolbox, achieving frame rates at about 18 fps and using the new toolbox got to around 70!).

Note: I you need speed in image apps using Matlab, you should really consider using OpenCV libs through mex to get a decent performance in image manipulation.

Comment: when I type 'videoinput' or 'getdata', it says it's undefined function, which add on is it from?

Comment: https://www.mathworks.com/help/imaq/videoinput.html?requestedDomain=www.mathworks.com