# Processing image from real-time camera in Matlab

Tags: matlab, capture

I have a problem: I have 2 axes. One for preview, other for testing (do st).
When I capture 1 image to testing (losed 5s), Screen preview was stoped wait for testing after 5s continue...
I want to the camera don't stop. Can anybody help me ? Thanks in advance !

```
vid = videoinput('winvideo', 1, 'YUY2_640x480');
vid.FramesPerTrigger = 1;
vid.ReturnedColorspace = 'rgb';
triggerconfig(vid, 'manual');
vidRes = get(vid, 'VideoResolution');
imWidth = vidRes(1);
imHeight = vidRes(2);
nBands = get(vid, 'NumberOfBands');
hImage = image(zeros(imHeight, imWidth, nBands), 'parent', handles.axes2);
preview(vid, hImage);

start(vid);% video is started

while(1)
    g=getsnapshot(vid); %get current frame

    %- Testing lost 5 secs
end
```

Comment: If without the `while`, you try taking a single snapshot while the preview is open, how long does it take? (Not a direct answer, but you may also want to check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8901824/getsnapshot-speedup )

Comment: I try...but when snapshot, do stuff, camera stopped.